# rkt networking on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rkt

I am trying to run a simple rkt container on ubuntu 16.10. I am having some networking problems. Here are the commands I ran.

`sudo rkt run --interactive quay.io/coreos/alpine-sh`

Then running:

`/ # ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
/ # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=58 time=6.815 ms`

After coming out:
`sudo rkt list
UUID        APP     IMAGE NAME          STATE   CREATED     STARTED     NETWORKS
4d35bf55    alpine-sh   quay.io/coreos/alpine-sh:latest exited  40 seconds ago  39 seconds ago`

As you can see network tab is empty. Here is my iptables:

`sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.16.28.0/24

ACCEPT     all  --  172.16.28.0/24       anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Answer (score 0):

try adding --dns

`sudo rkt run --interactive quay.io/coreos/alpine-sh --dns=8.8.8.8`

btw 8.8.8.8 is the address of google's DNS server